# Как проверить 2 массива с разными количествами элементов?

Tags: php, массивы, сравнение

Вопрос в том есть два массива с разными количествами элементов и надо проверить какие элементы  не найдены в $array2 и их вывести, Пример:

```
$array1 = array (Вода Легенда 19 л.qq, 
    Вода Легенда 10 л. (пакетqq),  
    Стаканодержатель,  
    Переходник для диспенсера );  
$array2 = array (Стаканодержатель,  
    Переходник для диспенсера );
```

// результат должен быть Вода Легенда 19 л.qq и Вода Легенда 10 л. (пакетqq) не найдены
`$array2` может быть пустым, равен, но не может быть больше чем `$array1`? 
За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию array_diff (http://www.php.su/array_diff())

```
$result = array_diff ($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```